# How to detect "Allow only while using the app" permission when user give location permission

Tags: android, permissions, runtime-permissions

This is a basic question but I not find a solution for this scenario. I used "Dexter" library to ask for runtime permissions. I need to get background location permission so that I ask for permission , then I saw in Android Q there is an option "Allow only while using the app" , but while using dexter I'm unable to detect when user choose this option. Can anyone help me how I solve this condition?

Comment: "Can anyone help me how I solve this condition?" -- there is nothing to solve. The user can revoke your permissions at any time, for any reason. Whether the user does this manually or via options like this one (or newer options on Android 11) is up to the user. And AFAIK there is no way to determine whether the user chose one of these automatic-removal options.

Comment: Then if  I like to get location updates of user even after user close or kill app like app for "Riders", how i achieve this ? Can we not do that thing now?

Comment: "Then if I like to get location updates of user even after user close or kill app like app for "Riders", how i achieve this ?" -- there is a separate `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission for that: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/privacy/changes#app-access-device-location. Note that this changed a bit in Android 11: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the one explained by the Dexter team? (Example on requesting ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission is there)

[Application stuck when requesting ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION](https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter/issues/240#issuecomment-551657778)

And in Google's Official API, they mentioned the new addition to Background Location check: ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

[Background location access checklist](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background#checklist)

This API specifically added for just that: to check if user chooses to permit location while using the app (or means, app in foreground, not background) or not

Comment: I already saw this question ion github. I already ask permission request with fine location that is ok, my problem is when user allow while using the app and for all time how i detect these 2 separately

Comment: @Addy then add one more request for ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION. The only note is that in android 11, you have to ask these 2 permission separately (not combined, and foreground first then background) or else you lose access on both (foreground and background). CommonsWare has provided link to that behaviour explanation

Answer (score 0):

I'm here a bit late. But I have the exact response for you and for everyone that is looking for the same. The clue is to handle the request permission result.

If you are asking for Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION and Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION at the same time then android will call you on `onRequestPermissionsResult` with different set arguments depends of user response. In any case `permissions` argument will be the same:

```
["android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION", "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION."]
```

Then if user allow "Only this time" or "While using.." you will receive in `grantResults` argument 0 (true) for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION and -1 (false) for ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION:

```java
[-1, 0]
```

But if user allow "all the time" you will receive:

```java
[0, 0]
```

Finally is user "denies":

```java
[-1, -1]
```

**Again, the clue is yo know that allow "all the time" implies ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION grants.**

```java
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, [Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION], 100)
...

public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (grantResults[0] == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_DENIED && grantResults[1] == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
    // user denies
    }
    if (grantResults[0] == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_DENIED && grantResults[1] == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // user allow while using
    }
    if (grantResults[0] == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED && grantResults[1] == PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    // user allow all the time
    }
}
```